# MS SQL Server 2022 High CPU Usage Spikes Every Minute under no Load (Dual Processor)

Tags: sql-server, cpu, sql-server-2022

Brand new MS SQL Server Standard 2022 Installation on a Dual Xeon 3416 system doing nothing and configured to do nothing fancy.

Every minute, on the minute for about 6 seconds there is a massive CPU SPike (lots of green/red (kernel?)) under no load/no queries.

I have confirmed that when the spike happens any query running hangs until the spike is over making the database unusable every minute.

I have scoured various logs/event viewer and see nothing being logged every minute that coincides with the spikes.

From my understanding of the table below the Resource Monitor is the source of this with the PREEMPTIVE  and SOS Scheduler Yield. I'm assuming that this is related to a dual processor and/or hyper threading issue/configuration but can't find any resources to help me troubleshoot/provide guidelines on what needs to be looked at.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

```
spid cpu percentileCPU physical_io memusage cmd lastwaittype
69 1033796 16 0 0 RESOURCE MONITOR PREEMPTIVE_XE_CALLBACKEXECUTE
72 921921 14 0 0 RESOURCE MONITOR SLEEP_TASK
74 905828 14 0 0 RESOURCE MONITOR SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD
76 896484 13 0 0 RESOURCE MONITOR SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD
75 839546 13 0 0 RESOURCE MONITOR SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD
67 598390 9 0 0 RESOURCE MONITOR SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD
68 535640 8 0 0 RESOURCE MONITOR SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD
73 531671 8 0 0 RESOURCE MONITOR SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD
```

So, following a suggestion from [SQLHack on SOS_Scheduler_Yields](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-handle-excessive-sos_scheduler_yield-wait-type-values-in-sql-server/) I investigated and saw that the power plan was set to "Balance". I changed it to "High Performance" and restarted SQL Server and the problem seemed to go away for 31 minutes (30 + 1?)

I then noticed that at the same time it started up the below message got logged a single time. The server has 512GB of ram and SQL Server is only using about 5GB of ram (Process Explorer reports it having a consistent a Private Byte of about 5GB and a working set of about 4GB (doing nothing)). The total Operating System is using 17.6GB System Commit / 16.6GB Physical Ram.

After this message is logged every minute the SQL Server does its heavy CPU spike.

```
A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 0 seconds. Working set (KB): 2247128, committed (KB): 4406376, memory utilization: 50%%.
```

[image]

**Solved**

I ended up manually limiting SQL Server to use 128GB (which i believe is Std max), Enabling Lock Memory Privilege on the SQL Service User, verifying that SQL Server restarted with Locking enabled (via logging) AND STILL it kept paging out and massively spiking every minute afterwards.

This led me to an article about using xperf to find contiguous memory generation/allocation

```
xperf.exe -on PROC_THREAD+LOADER+MEMINFO+CONTMEMGEN -stackwalk ContiguousMemoryGeneration -f ContMem.etl
```

I let this run, and then tried to pinpoint the time when the page out occurred.

From the best I could tell the page out seemed to coincide with a long running MoUsoWorker.exe process terminating (not an ETW/XPerf expert by any means).

Went down a path of trying to make sure that MoUsoWorker was not long lived and while doing this stumbled upon the SuperFetch service cleverly disguised as *definitely-not-SuperFetch*.

***Disabled SuperFetch service* and took care of MoUsoWorker (unfortunately in the same go).**

SQL Service has been running for 1 hour 20 minutes as I type without paging out and then subsequently non-stop CPU spiking . Previously the longest was 45 minutes (generally 10-30 minutes~)

**knock on wood**.

SuperFetch sounds like something that could potentially cause conflicts with SQL Server. After the fact I'm not seeing any major conflicts documented though.

Comment: Anything else installed and / or running on the machine itself (outside of the SQL Server instance), e.g. antivirus? How are you monitoring the CPU spike? What does [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) show when ran during the spike?

Comment: Hi JD. Thanks for the response/questions. Nothing else running. Brand new Windows Server / SQL installation. CPU spike was caught by ProcessExplorer. Verified that the CPU Spikes were causing legitimate problems by attempting to run queries during the 4-6 second duration of the spikes. I've since updated my question as I did two things (at the same time), one of which seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: I mean you're attacking this from a very specific and deep angle that is not usual. Whatever you got going on sounds quite odd. I'd cover all the basics of making sure you're on the latest OS patch and SQL Server 2022 patch, verify no hardware issues, and I'd look at what the queries you're running are waiting on per [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) when the CPU spikes. What does the CPU get to when it spikes? ProcessExplorer calls out `SQLServer.exe` for the CPU spikes or some other process? You may even be hitting some kind of bug in 2022, worth contacting Microsoft for support on.

Comment: I'd already spent a day eliminating the usual sus (updates, no queries or users, etc).  Image attached, and yes I know the spike doesn't look like much but it represents 7% of 2 x 20 x 2 cores/threads (and verified blocking any running queries during spike). Broken out Per Graph CPU and it was red lining on almost 1/3+ of the cores. Either way, the issue is resolved from one of the two aforementioned last fixes. **Would love to hear from somebody on the MS SQL Server Side whether SuperFetch could have been causing a continguous mem allocation, accidentally forcing SQL Server to page out**

Comment: And to answer your question sp_WhoIsActive and the 30+ other troubleshooting queries mostly elicited what they should have. That it was empty, doing nothing, etc. But symptoms of Extreme memory pressure on a system with 1/2 TB of ram at near 0% utilization, running nothing, doing nothing.

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted some of the questions I've asked. You've specified the spike is slowing *other* queries down. [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) will tell you what those *other* queries are waiting on specifically (e.g. the `wait_info` column among other helpful columns). I'd be curious what it reports that those queries are waiting on, e.g. something directly indicative of CPU contention or another clue perhaps.

Comment: May things can cause these issues. The problem here is that no one is going to be able to definitively tell you the root cause of your issues as we have no access to the data or environment. Having dealt with these issues on a day to day basis for years, without looking at the data it's going to be impossible. Can other services cause problems, yes, but again we have no actual evidence. We'd need much more data and access to said data, including what a "bad time" looks like versus a "good time". This also isn't a SQL Server issue, SQL is a victim in the memory department.

Comment: I had a similar problem a long time ago, not on sql 2022 but 2014 - believe it or not the problem was the connectivity coming from one of the webservers. Switching off that server, and the sql server box would work fine again. so yeah it is difficult to work out what is causing this issue. in that case it was the sql server exe using the cpu. but there were nothing more than normal inside its workload.